# Python multiprocessing shared memory error on close

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pyarrow

I am using Python multiprocessing shared memory.

I see the following error when I try to close a SharedMemory object: BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer

Can someone please let me know what this error means?

Here is how to reproduce: I am using Pyarrow

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1000,1000)))
batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_pandas(a)

mock_sink = pa.MockOutputStream()
with pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(mock_sink, batch.schema) as stream_writer:
    stream_writer.write_batch(batch)

data_size = mock_sink.size()
print(data_size)
shm_a = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=data_size)

buf = pa.py_buffer(shm_a.buf)
stream = pa.FixedSizeBufferWriter(buf)
with pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(stream, batch.schema) as stream_writer:
    stream_writer.write_batch(batch)
print(shm_a.name)
shm_a.close()
```

Comment: It's very hard to say anything without any code / minimal working example - please provide some more details.

Comment: just did. I have a dependency on pyarrow==6.0.1

Comment: I tried to run this, but `data_size` is undefined - please fix this.

Comment: I just fixed it. I have no idea why that line failed to copy

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem. After some digging, I found some clue:

[image]

From the code above, you can see that once we create a `pa.py_buffer` object from share memory's `buf`, `shm.buf` can't be released. After we delete that `py_buffer` object, it can be released successfully without throwing the `BufferError` exception.

So the solution I came up to solve my problem is as follows:
[image]

This may not be a perfect solution. If anybody comes up with better ones, please post it.

Also note that the `BufferError` still seem to arise when we read the shared memory from multiple processes. I am still working on it.

Comment: I don't believe it solved my problem...

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, just edited the answer. The solution is temporary, if you found better ones, please post it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That resolved my problem but now, that I'm trying to put dataframes of pyarrow types into a shared memory I'm getting this problem again. If you learn something more about this please visit my question here: [BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer trying to close a shared memory where I put a dataframe of pyarrow data type values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481829/buffererror-memoryview-has-1-exported-buffer-trying-to-close-a-shared-memory-wh)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).