# BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer trying to close a shared memory where I put a dataframe of pyarrow data type values

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, pyarrow, memoryview

I'm trying to put dataframes of different types in multiprocessing shared memory. When I'm using dataframes that contain python types I've no problem, but when I use pyarrow types I've problems closing the Shared Memories. I've a function to put a dataframe to the Shared Memory and another to receive this dataframe. I have two problems when I'm using Arrow types like string[pyarrow] inside a dataframe:

- When I call the close on the sm_put and after receiving the dataframe I call the close on the sm_get I get instantly an error, that causes the code to stop executing: sm_get.close() -> self.close() -> self._buf.release() -> BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer.
- When I call the close on the sm_put, and I don't call the close on the sm_get, I've no problem instantly, but I get a warning after a while (that surprises me because I don't call any function self.close()): self.close() -> self._buf.release() -> BufferError: memoryview has 1 exported buffer.

My functions to put the dataframe to the shared memory and to receive the dataframe from shared memory are these:

```
> def put_df(data, logTime, logSize, usingArrow=False):
>     if(usingArrow):
>         table = (pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(data)).combine_chunks()
>         record_batch = table.to_batches(max_chunksize = sys.maxsize)[0]
>     else:
>         record_batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_pandas(data)  
>     # Determine the size of buffer to request from the shared memory
>     mock_sink = pa.MockOutputStream()
>     stream_writer = pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(mock_sink, record_batch.schema)
>     stream_writer.write_batch(record_batch)
>     stream_writer.close()
>     data_size = mock_sink.size()
>     
>     sm_put = SharedMemory(create=True, size=data_size)
>     buffer = pa.py_buffer(sm_put.buf)
> 
>     # Write the PyArrow RecordBatch to SharedMemory
>     stream = pa.FixedSizeBufferWriter(buffer)
>     stream_writer = pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(stream, record_batch.schema)
>     stream_writer.write_batch(record_batch)
>     stream_writer.close()
> 
>     del stream_writer
>     del stream
>     del buffer
>     if(usingArrow):
>         del table
>     del record_batch
> 
>     sm_put.close()
>     return sm_put.name 
> 
> def get_df(sm_get_name, logTime, logSize, usingArrow=False):
>     sm_get = SharedMemory(name = sm_get_name, create = False)
>     buffer = pa.BufferReader(sm_get.buf)
> 
>     # Convert object back into an Arrow RecordBatch
>     reader = pa.RecordBatchStreamReader(buffer)
>     record_batch = reader.read_next_batch()
> 
>     # Convert back into Pandas
>     if(usingArrow):
>         data = record_batch.to_pandas(types_mapper = pd.ArrowDtype)
>     else:
>         data = record_batch.to_pandas()
>            
>     del buffer
>     del reader
>     del record_batch
> 
>     sm_get.close()
>     sm_get.unlink()
> 
>     return data
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     names = [ "0", "1"]
>     types = { "0": "string[pyarrow]", "1": "string[pyarrow]" }
>     df = pd.read_csv(open(file, "r"), index_col=False, header=None, names=names, dtype=types, engine="c")
>     sm_get_name = put_df(df)
>     data = get_df(sm_get_name=sm_get_name)
```

I've seen that when I'm trying to del the pyarrow objects (like table or record_batch) the memory is not released instantly (I'm checking It with the memory_profiler library). This could be the problem, someone know If that can be the problem and how can I solve It?

I'm using pyarrow 11.0.0 and pandas 1.5.3

The errors are these:
[Error appeared when I do sm_put.close() and sm_get.close()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkLSF.jpg)
[Error appeared when I only do the sm_put.close() or I don't call any close() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giVoR.jpg)

The profile of memory when I'm using pd.ArrowDtype inside dataframes makes me think about memory leaks that can cause the BufferError:

[Profile of memory using dataframes with pd.ArrowDtpe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYSpV.jpg)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example for your issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to completely reproduce your example. My understanding is that `put_df` is doing  the right thing. But in `get_df`, the record_batch is holding to a view of the buffer / shared memory (in an effort to avoid copying data).

It means that you shouldn't hold on to the record batch (and the reader) before you close the shared memory.

I got it to work, but it's not very different from your solution. All I did is make sure the `RecordBatchStreamReader` is closed.

```
def get_df(sm_get_name):
    sm_get = SharedMemory(name = sm_get_name, create = False)
    buffer = pa.BufferReader(sm_get.buf)

    with pa.RecordBatchStreamReader(buffer) as reader:
        record_batch = reader.read_next_batch()
        df = record_batch.to_pandas()
        del record_batch
    del reader
    del buffer

    sm_get.close()
    sm_get.unlink()

    return df
```

It's also possible that using `pd.ArrowDtype` doesn't work because it means the shared memory data isn't copied at all. Whereas the standard `to_pandas` implementation copies the data from arrow to numpy format.

PS:

> the memory is not released instantly (I'm checking It with the memory_profiler library)

python doesn't immediately release the memory that has been freed to the OS. So don't expect the process memory to decrease. Instead you should jsut  make sure that the memory doesn't increase if you call this function several times.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for the answer!
The problems that I get is using data = record_batch.to_pandas(types_mapper = pd.ArrowDtype). If I use the python types I've no problem.
When I'm using pd.ArrowDtype and profiling the memory I realised that the del on the table (put_df) has no effect. This can cause my buffererror but I don't know how to solve it. In the question above I added an image where you can see the profile  of memory using pd.ArrowDtype inside the dataframe.
I posted the question also in an arrow blog: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/36126

Comment: The issue isn't in `put_df`. The resulting `pd.DataFrame`, when using `pd.ArrowDtype` is pointing to an area of memory in the shared memory that you are closing. The work around would be to force it to copy when either reading the data or converting it to pandas. But I can't figure out how to do it by looking at the doc.

Comment: Okey I've solved that calling del on data. I will change my code to do all the opeartations on the variable data before closing the sm_get. Thank you a lot!